# Wordpress-Header transparent

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need some help in making the header of the following site transparent so the below image also will be visible in the header. I tried overriding the CSS, but it did not work.

https://essenceprotocol.io

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've have found where you can set de background to transparent.

```css
.stm-header__row_color {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```